# Ruby Quiz setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

*Got the answer in the comments in the first answer listed, it was verifying all along, I just had to add the flash to the view.*

How can I alter this code to make it verify the answer is correct ?

I followed this tutorial http://quizzsystem.comyr.com/web-page/

- the error I get right now when hitting the submit answer button is "No route matches [POST] "/quizzs/check/1"- so  it looks like it is not verifying the answer and redirecting but just searching for another page called "check" to display.

what it is supposed to do is run check (/quizzs_controller.rb) on an answer to verify if it is correct or not

/quizzs_controller.rb

```
class QuizzsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quizz, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authenticate, :except=>[:home, :answering, :answer, :check]

 ...

 def check
   @quizz = Quizz.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
     if params[:ans][0].to_i==@quizz.correctAns
      flash[:notice] = "<b>Congratulation. You gave the correct answer to the question: " + @quizz.question + "</b>"  
       format.html { redirect_to({:controller => "quizzs", :action =>  "answering",:id=>"1" } ) }
      format.xml { head :ok }
    else
      flash[:notice] = "<b p style='color: red'>I am sorry but that is not the right answer to the question: " + @quizz.question + "</b>"
      format.html { redirect_to({:controller => "quizzs", :action =>   "answering",:id=>"1" } ) }
      format.xml { head :ok }
    end 
  end
 end

...
```

So when you hit the button in the view below it runs 'check' to verify the answer, display the corresponding message on the page it redirects to which is  /answering.html.erb.

/answer.html.erb

*I added the "=" sign before form_tag, that is the only change from the original code (unless there is a typo I still have not caught)

```
   ...


  <%= form_tag( :action => "check",:id => @quizz.id) do %>
<p>
  <b>The correct answer is number: </b>
   <%= text_field :ans,params[:ans]%>
 </p>

<p><%= submit_tag("check")%></P>

    <%end%>

<%= link_to 'Back', {:controller => "quizzs", :action => "answering",:id=>"1" } %>

...
```

render back to this page and display the message

/answering.html.erb

```
<h2>Which question do you want to answer</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Question</th>
</tr>
<%@quizzs.each do |quizz|%>
<tr>
    <td><%=h quizz.question %></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<> Answer this', :controller => "quizzs", :action => "answer", :id =>quizz.id%></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
</table>
<br />
```

But instead what happens is it seems to look for a route called 'check' instead of verifying whether or not the question is correct.

I hope that is a better presentation of my question, I am still new to this stuff.

Comment: I'd love to help you if you'll just narrow down your question and relevant code/errors.  Helping with beginner's questions is usually quick and thorough as long as you don't knock us out with walls-of-text and huge multi-part questions.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry about that I tried to narrow down the focus to be more specific, hope this is a better presented question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**resources :quizzs** will only generate routes for **Create/Read/Update/Destroy** actions. For any custom actions in the controller, a new route entry needs to be added to the routes.rb file. one way to do this is to declare the new action under the resources block like this.

```
resources :quizzs do
   member do
     patch 'check'
   end
end
```

If you run `rake routes` from your shell, you should see a line which will have quizzs#check. Any route which is not present in the output of `rake routes` is not known to Rails.

Hope this helps solve the problem and helps you understand how routing works.

Comment: thanks for you time and answer Mr. Kandala, I apologize I cannot articulate  my question better, as far as I can tell check is not supposed to be another page, it is supposed to be an action that runs on the answer to verify correct or incorrect, so instead of being a route it is supposed to be an action (not sure if that term is correct) and in the tutorial I followed it does that, but when I tried recreating it instead of verifying the answer it tries to redirect to a page that does not exist (and as far as I can tell from the tutorial is not ever created).  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Also, I did try putting that code in but it didn't verify the answer it still pointed to a 'check' page.

Comment: @RockwellRice when you say it still points to a 'check' page. The error is the same ("No route matches...")

Comment: yes the error is the same, the post route shows up in the routes error part but the id and check are switched around, I am trying to find that in the code somewhere right now.

Comment: Just to clarify, a route in the routes file means a valid URL in the application irrespective of whether that URL takes the user to a new page or updates part of the current page (using Ajax & Javascript). A route is identified by controller and the action and request parameters if any (quizzs/:id/check). Please remember, you have to add custom routes in the routes.rb file for all the custom routes (answer, answering etc) with appropriate VERB (GET/PUT/PATCH). Is it still complaining about quizzs#check or some other route ?

Comment: it redirects back to the page it is supposed to but still is not verifying whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: @RockwellRice - Irrespective of whether the answer is correct or wrong, you are redirecting the user to the /answering page (answering.html.erb view). The only way for the user to know if the answer is correct or not is though the flash message. But there seems to be no code in the view file to show that, unless you have that code snippet in the layout file. If not, please add <%= flash[:notice] %> to the answering.html.erb to show the flash message that you are setting in the controller. Hope this hint helps.

Comment: Ah that did it!  I have been working on trying to create this for a long time, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your "check" action isn't routed. Below `resources :quizzs` add

```
patch 'quizzs/check/:id.:format' to: 'quizzs#check' #this names might be different
```

I hope this solves your issue.

PD: You can always use `rake routes` in your terminal to check the routes you have defined and their methods.

GL & HF.

Comment: Then add this route in adition to to the "gets" you have. I'm blind here as this isn't my developing machine.

Comment: I did try that before (and just now again) but it does not change the error. I think I am struggling trying to articulate my question.  I do not need to create a check route, check is supposed to verify the answer (correct or incorrect) and once it does that display the corresponding message when it redirects, It does that in the tutorial I followed but does not do it when I run it and I cannot figure out why(sorry I am new to this stuff hope that explanation makes sense).

Comment: Check out what `rake routes` outputs. and give http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html a try. As a side note, you don't need to re-define @quizz since you have a before_action that does that.